# length does not work after multiplication

Tags: javascript, multiplication

Edit: Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/VnXtP/

Why dosent this work?
http://jsfiddle.net/uc7kT/

```
<input type="text" name="item_quantity" id="item_quantity" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="item_price" id="item_price" value="24998" hidden="hidden" />

$('#item_quantity').change(function() {
    var quantity = $('#item_quantity').val();
    var price = $('#item_price').val();
    var total =  quantity * price;

    alert(total.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length is defined for strings, not numbers.  If you wish to do this as a mathematical operation, you must convert the input strings to numbers first.  If you actually want the length of the number string (I don't know why you would), you need to convert the number to a string first:

```
$('#item_quantity').change(function() {
    var quantity = parseInt($('#item_quantity').val(), 10);
    var price = parseFloat($('#item_price').val());
    var total =  quantity * price;

    alert(total.toString().length);
});
```

Comment: It was toString() (I had already found out about parseInt) that solved it:
alert(total.toString().length);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
alert(total);
```

Instead of:

```
alert(total.length);
```

You may also want to consider converting the values of the input to a float, or integer value before performing the math.

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/uc7kT/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
var quantity = $('#item_quantity').val();
 var price = $('#item_price').val();
```

`item_quantity` and `item_price` are text inputs, and you need to change it to Integer before you multiply. use parseInt() to do it.

```
var quantity = parseInt($('#item_quantity').val(),10);
     var price = parseInt($('#item_price').val(),10);
```

and use `alert(total);` not `alert(total.length);`

Answer (score 0):

total is a number. It does not have the property "length".

Try

```
alert(total);
```

I guess that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript a number is a number and a string is a string.

What can be sometimes confusing is that a number can automagically become a string when that is needed (for example adding a string to it).

Numbers do not have a `length` property, strings instead do. Also in javascript when you ask an object for a property that is not present normally you just get the `undefined` value.